# HTML component actions rerouting in express

Tags: node.js, express, shared-hosting

I am deploying a web app using node js and express to my shared hosting domain, however I cannot find a way to reroute my form actions and button links to the correct destination since they are being served from a subdirectory in the host.

I coded my app testing from my own pc, therefore using localhost as the url for my server, then I declared routes in express like `/object/add`, `/object/edit/:id`, `/object/list`, etc...

They all seem to work, however I also used Handlebars for the views, therefore I have components like

```
  <form action="/object/edit/{{id}}" method="POST">
       <div class="form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
       </div>
  </form>
```

In localhost it works, however I am trying to deploy it to a domain under a subdirectory `mydomain.com/app/crud`, when I do that my redirections point to 
`mydomain.com/object/add` instead of `mydomain.com/app/crud/object/add`, therefore I get error pages.

I already tried setting up my app under a route but although that works for express routing it does not change the URLs that come from the HTML components.

My current Express objects looks like this

```
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();
router.use(require("./routes"));
router.use("/object", require("./routes/object"));
router.use("/personality", require("./routes/personality"));
app.use(host.baseUrl, router);
```

and my Routers are like

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const pool = require("../database");

router.get("/add", (req, res) => {
  res.render("object/add");
});

router.post("/add", async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  const object= {
    name
  };
await pool.query("INSERT INTO objectset ?", [object]);
  res.redirect("/object");
});

...

module.exports = router;
```

I also tried using

```
function handleRedirect(req, res) {
  const targetUrl = targetBaseUrl + req.originalUrl;
  res.redirect(targetUrl);
}
app.get('*', handleRedirect);
```

but it messes up all my css requests and practically every other routing.

Is there a way I can manage those redirections? Maybe htmlredirects can be used instead?

Comment: random guess here, did you try using relative URL's? like `<form action="object/edit/{{id}}"`

Comment: @AndrewLohr yes I did and it works but I must set all of them depending on how many parts does the route has and on which file I am involving them and end up having things like `../../../object/list`

Comment: hm if you're just doing a http requests from forms or js to your server you shouldn't have to do that. They all should just be what they are without the leading slash. Maybe I'm missing some context here.

Comment: @AndrewLohr I am doing the http requests as shown in the first code from the URL `mydomain.com/app/crud/object/list`, but the resulting url does not returns `mydomain.com/app/crud/object/edit/{{id}}`, instead I have  `mydomain.com/object/edit/{{id}}`

Comment: right if you use relative URL's it would be based off the path already in the URL so `app/crud/` would be there when you request `object/edit/{id}` not sure why you think you have to put `../../../` you shouldn't have to

Comment: @AndrewLohr the problem is that `app/crud/` is not there if I don't use relative URL's, in all redirections it takes it out, I have to use `../../../` because if I use relative URL's without it I end with something like `mydomain.com/app/crud/object/list/object/edit/{{id}}`